# How to add columns to collection table java jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm using spring jpa. 
I have the following entity:

```
public class CountryParameter extends Parameter {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Country.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "Parameter_Countries", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "segmentParameter_id"))
    @Column(name = "country")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Country> countries;
```

Edit: country is en enum.

The collection table has only 2 columns: parameter_id and country, I would like to add more like id.

how can I do this?

Comment: and Country is what class?

Comment: So if that is an enum, then the CollectionTable will have 2 columns ... the id of the CountryParameter class, and the STRING representing the enum. That's how it is modelled in JPA. There is no option of an extra column, and i've no idea what this other column would be

Comment: If you want an ID, then create an entity with an ID and a country. Then use a OneToMany association between CountryParameter and this new entity.

Comment: @JBNizet I will try this!